# SignalR server error while attempting to call a hub method

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, signalr

I use signalR in my project. It works fine. In a part on my project, I need to use instant notification when a delete button is clicked. The button is in jQuery datatable. I used the following code:

```
var connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl("/signalRServer").withAutomaticReconnect().build();
            connection.start();
                 function DeleteData(pmId, mainFileName, fileName) {
                     if (confirm("Are you sure")) {
                        connection.invoke("PmPageUpdate", pmId).catch(function(err){
                        return console.error(err);
                     });
                         Delete(pmId, mainFileName, fileName);
                     } else {
                         return false;
                     }
                 }
```

When I debug, the hub method is not called. Console shows the following error:

> PmManagement:692 Error: Failed to invoke 'PmPageUpdate' due to an
> error on the server.
> at H. (signalr.js:1:13973)
> at L.I (signalr.js:1:14804)
> at X.L.connection.onreceive (signalr.js:1:10649)
> at WebSocket.r.onmessage (signalr.js:1:27565)

How can I fix this?

**Update:**
The followings are codes I've written for the hub. Some methods that are not related to this question has been ignored.
Hub:

```
    private readonly IUserRepository _userRepository;
    private readonly ICostCenterRepository _costcenterRepository;
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContext;
    private readonly INotificationRepository _notificationRepository;
    private readonly IMessageRepository _messageRepository;
    private readonly IPmRepository _pmRepository;

    public MessageHub(IUserRepository userRepository, ICostCenterRepository costcenterRepository, IHttpContextAccessor httpContext,
        INotificationRepository notificationRepository, IMessageRepository messageRepository, IPmRepository pmRepository)
    {
        _userRepository = userRepository;
        _costcenterRepository = costcenterRepository;
        _httpContext = httpContext;
        _notificationRepository = notificationRepository;
        _messageRepository = messageRepository;
        _pmRepository = pmRepository;
    }
    //define a dictionary to store the userid.
    private static Dictionary<string, List<string>> NtoIdMappingTable = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();

    public Task JoinNotificationGroup(string groupName)
    {
        return Groups.AddToGroupAsync(Context.ConnectionId, groupName);
    }
    public Task LeaveNotificationGroup(string groupName)
    {
        return Groups.RemoveFromGroupAsync(Context.ConnectionId, groupName);
    }
    public override async Task OnConnectedAsync()
    {
        var username = Context.User.Identity.Name;
        var userId = Context.UserIdentifier;
        List<string> userIds;

        //store the userid to the list.
        if (!NtoIdMappingTable.TryGetValue(username, out userIds))
        {
            userIds = new List<string>();
            userIds.Add(userId);

            NtoIdMappingTable.Add(username, userIds);
        }
        else
        {
            userIds.Add(userId);
        }

        await base.OnConnectedAsync();
    }

    public override async Task OnDisconnectedAsync(Exception exception)
    {
        var username = Context.User.Identity.Name;

        //remove userid from the List
        if (NtoIdMappingTable.ContainsKey(username))
        {
            NtoIdMappingTable.Remove(username);
        }
        await base.OnDisconnectedAsync(exception);
    }
            string username = _userRepository.GetUsernameByCostCenter(pmId).ToString();
            var userId = NtoIdMappingTable.GetValueOrDefault(username);
            await Clients.User(userId.ToString()).SendAsync("SignalReceiver");
        }
```

Comment: Add the server side method to your question.

Comment: @lordvlad30 I updated.

Comment: I tried to use IHubConrext and send signal from the controller instead of client side. I solved my problem by an another way, but I don't know why this way cause problem.

Comment: seems like you made a mistake copying the code, your method `public async Task PmPageUpdate(int pmId)` has no body defined.

Comment: Are all dependencies registered?

Comment: Have you tried a try-catch block around the code in the method that does not work?

Comment: Yes, All dependencies have been registered in `program.cs`. I have three connection string in the view. They all have a same name but in different places..

Comment: There is no method called ´PmPageUpdate´ in your hub code?